# Resize WooCommerce Thumbnails

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, thumbnails

I'm making a WordPress website with WooCommerce and I need to resize the product thumbnails in the display products (category) page.

In particular I have this situation: [image]

And I'd like to have a page like this: [image]

Is it possible? I've checked that the CSS class should be `img.attachment-shop_catalog.wp-post-image` and I've tried with `-webkit-transform:scale(1.2);` but my product image thumbnails overlap. It's not a problem of WooCommerce images settings (the "force hard crop" option is disabled), so I think I have to add a custom CSS. Could you help me to fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I would have checked all surrounding classes cause it is probably limited by them, or there is padding-right set on outer container.

I would have tried to find (using Chrome possibilities) and try first to locally resize them and product container in CSS.

Comment: And how can I resize the product container only for thumbnails in CSS? Which class should I edit? Thanks!

Comment: If you could give link to website using WooCommerce (best would be your site) I could help you, but you need to point exact situation - on what type of pages you want to change it (direct link to some example page with that thumbnails).

Comment: Thank you, but I'm using WampServer to develop this website locally, so I can't provide you a link! However I want to change it in all the display product pages (categories), that are automatically generated by WooCommerce. Is there another way to fix this? Thank you once more.

Comment: By changing CSS responsible for one of them You change all of them - CSS is universal. Post HTML code generated on one of that product pages + all CSS that it requires.

Comment: Nice! Thank you. Do you think I should link to another website (like Pastebin) or can I post it directly here on Stackoverflow?

Comment: Hello, I just copied the code of my webpage [here](http://pastebin.com/D2Y4w9NR), and [here](http://pastebin.com/v1jgGG8H) is the related CSS. I hope you can help me to resize the products thumbnails as described before. Thanks in advance!